# Update Angular Version using angular-cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I currently have an Angular project which has an angular version 4.0.0.
Is it possible to upgrade the project to 4.3.0 using angular-cli?

Comment: you can simply run `npm update --save` to update to the latest version of angular and all dependency libraries.

Comment: @ryan-dsouza you can use @pengyy method, but you might not want to update all packages, in that case you have to manually change the versions in `package.json`. to see all old packages, run `npm outdated`.

Comment: This command just updates Angular to the latest: npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save

Answer (score 0):

Using angular-cli do not prevent you from updating your dependencies as usual. You could update "package.json" manually if you are using npm@3.x but if you are using npm@5.x you need to write in the command line npm update @angular/{package_name}